# How do you say "Save Room" the context of detainment in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning-in-context, word

Translations from online that I know isn't what I meant:

**保存室** = Save room, for the storage of food and supplies.

**隔离所** = Quarantined area/room.

**急症室 / 拯救室 / 救助室** = Emergency room.

---

Isolation or detention related:

**安全房 = Save Room / Safe Room / Panic Room**; in regards to protecting someone from ongoing danger. (Such as those in school settings. Sometimes it can be written as both "Safe" or "Save" based on the context of the area.

**禁闭室 = Detention room**; solitary confined room. Sometimes used in school when the student has done wrong or is deemed dangerous. Resulting in suspension.
（在校园中用于惩罚或隔离学生的房间。比如做了坏事而被停学的学生。也可以是指隔离囚犯的房间。）

**拘留室 = Holding cell / Detention cell in prison.**; a place used to temporarily detain prisoners or suspects for further interrogation or processing.
（用于暂时拘留犯人或嫌疑人进一步的审讯或处理的地方。）

**监禁牢房 / 临禁闭室 = prison cell /incarceration cell.**

Comment: Is "Save Room"  a common term? Google results come up with mostly games or songs

Comment: "containing someone that is dangerous" is  囚室(prison cell); " protecting someone from ongoing danger" is 安全屋 (safe house)

Comment: Ok, i messed uo save and safe! I shall edit it later, sorry

Comment: So I did some googling, and one source says that in cases, 'save' can mean to 'prevent from harm', like saving in a game to prevent loss. While 'safe' is to be free from harm's reach, as in "safe room". I think both works in different contexts

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are confusing safe and save, easy to do, f and v:

保存室: storage room
隔离所 : isolation location/room
急症室 / 拯救室 / 救助室 : emergency room/emergency room/aid room

1. 监禁牢房: custodial cell (not likely found in a school)
2. 安全房: panic room

Gimme room!

Comment: Ok sorry for the mix up! 我没反应过来。I shall edit it afterward!

Comment: Ok, I am not sure why they wrote "Save Room" on my schedule. Safe Room does make more sense.

Comment: Nothing new. Other common mix ups are, ratify / rectify; literally / literary; then / than; complement / compliment; farther / further; principle / principal; stationary / stationery and so on.